# How to populate the User object with Mongoose and Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

I am trying to add a couple of attributes to the scaffolded MEAN.js User entity.

```
locationName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true 
}
```

I also have created another entity Book connected with User. Unfortunately, I think I do not quite grasp the concept behind the populate method because I am not able to "populate" the User entity with the locationName attribute.

I tried the following:

```
/**
 * List of Books
 */
exports.list = function(req, res) { 
Book.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName', 'locationName').exec(function(err, books) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(books);
        }
    });
};
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
/home/maurizio/Workspace/sbr-v1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:625
    throw new MongooseError.MissingSchemaError(name);
          ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "locationName".
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear, you should have a schema for the locationName.

If your location is just a string property in your user model and does not refer to separate model, you don't need and shouldn't use populate with it, it will simply be returned as a property of the returned user object from mongoose **find()** method.

If your want to make your location a stand alone entity (different mongodb document), you should have a mongoose model that defines your location object, aka have a file in your **app\models** name for example: **location.server.model.js** that contains something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = new Schema({   
    _id: String, 
    name: String
   //, add any additional properties
});

mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

Note that the _id here replaces the auto generated objectId, so this has to be unique, and this the property you should refer to in your User object, meaning if you have a location like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),   
    Location = mongoose.model('Location');
var _location = new Location({_id:'de', name:'Deutschland'});
```

you should refer to it in your User object like this:

```
var _user=new User({location:'de'});
//or:
 var _user=new User();
_user.location='de';
```

then you should be able to populate your location object with your user, like this:

```
User.find().populate('location').exec(function(err, _user) {
        if (err) {
            //handle error
        } else {
          //found user
          console.log(_user);
          //user is populated with location object, makes you able to do:
          console.log(_user.location.name);
        }
    });
```

I suggest you to further read in [mongodb data modeling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) Schemas, Models, Population.